# Get filename in url and open in new url (CMS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-management-system, contextmenu

In my strides to make work more efficient for my colleagues I'm trying to make an extension that enables editors to open images directly from front end, a task our CMS can't do.

The idea: When editors see an image they need to edit, they right-click and chose "Open in CMS". The extension picks up the filename (including file extension) and opens a new url in our CMS.

Example: 
Front end image url is http://www.justsomeurl.com/something/**product.jpg**

Image in the CSM can be accessed using search so that https://cms.justsomeurl.com/admin/appsomething/search:**product.jpg**

As a start I have tweaked an extension for Google Image search using this code:

```
function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {

    var url = 'https://cms.justsomeurl.com/admin/appsomething/search:' + info.srcUrl;

    chrome.windows.create({ url: url, width: 1024, height: 870 });
  };
}

/**
 * Context menu.
 */
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Find image in CMS",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["image"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

This of course sends the full url into the CMS search so it doesn't work. I have tried to combine it with another script  I [found](http://befused.com/javascript/get-filename-url):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

But since I basically have no idea what I'm doing it doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
Found a working solution:

```
function getClickHandler1() {
  return function(info, tab) {
    var url = 'https://cms.justsomeurl.com/admin/appsomething/search:' 
    + info.srcUrl.substring(info.srcUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    chrome.windows.create({ url: url, width: 1024, height: 870 });
  };
}
```

Comment: You need to use `info` parameter, of course. For example `var filename = info.srcUrl.substring ....`

Comment: Thank for helping out! Not sure how to approach this. I know it doesn't work but am I close?


    `var url = 'https://cms.justsomeurl.com/admin/search' + var info = window.location.pathname ;
var filename = info.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

Comment: Off course this is not working but can anyone give a a hint what's wrong?

` function getClickHandler() {
  return function(info, tab) {


var url = 'https://cms.justsomeurl.com/admin/search:'; 
var url_filename = window.location.pathname + info.srcUrl.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

var url+url_filename;

    // Create a new window to the info page.
    chrome.windows.create({ newurl: url, width: 1024, height: 870 });
  };
} `

Comment: Solution in the original post.